# Finding a strings that contain different substrings

Tags: python, numpy

The data i have is equivalent to this,

```
fun_strings=[]
fun_strings=['abc','cat','but','cab','mug','xyz']
```

I need to collect strings from this list that contain a

'u' or 't'

my desired output is,

```
['cat','but','mug']
```

It seems i can do this the slow way with a list

```
[x for x in fun_strings if 'u' in x or 't' in x]
```

Can i do this a faster way with numpy?

Comment: i'm assuming in your example you meant or

Comment: Your code it not doing what you think it is doing.`'u' and 't' in x` does not check for both `u` and `t` in x.

Comment: @chrisz Your right.  Do you know how i can fix it?

Comment: `[x for x in fun_strings if 'u' in x or 't' in x]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `or` in this case

```
fun_strings=['abc','cat','but','cab','mug','xyz']
[x for x in fun_strings if 'u' in x or 't' in x]
```

> ['cat', 'but', 'mug']

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the result :

```
print(list(filter(lambda x:'u' in x or 't' in x,fun_strings1)))
```

output:

```
['cat', 'but', 'mug']
```